# Update Office without opening an Office application

Tags: installation, update, microsoft-office

How do you trigger an Office update without opening an office application?

I need this to update Office after an offline install of o365, specifically in instances where Office needs to be updated between installing o365 apps and actually deploying the system.

I know you can do this by opening an office app, then going to File > Office Account > Update Options > Update Now, but I am trying to avoid triggering the Office activation / trial countdown before actually needing to sign a user in.

***edit:
I found a solution and posted it below.  Please feel free to contribute additional solutions especially if this does not work for older versions of Office.

Answer (score 21):

From command prompt:

`"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ClickToRun\OfficeC2RClient.exe" /update user`

This should trigger the Update GUI.

You can also do this silently by adding displaylevel=false forceappshutdown=true:

`"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ClickToRun\OfficeC2RClient.exe" /update user displaylevel=false forceappshutdown=true`

*source:*
[WaybackMachine: TechNet Blog: Office365 and its associated command-line and switches](https://web.archive.org/web/20190420045307/https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/odsupport/2014/03/03/the-new-update-now-feature-for-office-2013-click-to-run-for-office365-and-its-associated-command-line-and-switches/)

Comment: I added an answer with some additional commands that are handy.

Comment: Link is broken but here's an [archived copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20190420045307/https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/odsupport/2014/03/03/the-new-update-now-feature-for-office-2013-click-to-run-for-office365-and-its-associated-command-line-and-switches/) since the options still seem to apply.

Answer (score 12):

If you need to change the Office update channel for a client to switch them to the monthly update channel, you can run the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ClickToRun\OfficeC2RClient.exe" /changesetting Channel=Current
```

If you need to do this for a group of computers you can use `psexec` and a text file with the computer names like such:

```
psexec @computers.txt -d -n 3 cmd /c "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ClickToRun\OfficeC2RClient.exe" /changesetting Channel=Current
```

AND

```
psexec @computers.txt -d -n 3 cmd /c "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ClickToRun\OfficeC2RClient.exe" /update user updatepromptuser=false forceappshutdown=true displaylevel=false
```

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers are spot on, but for anyone that is looking to update to a particular version, you'll want to use the following command:

```
“C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ClickToRun\OfficeC2RClient.exe” /update user updatetoversion=X.X.X.X
```

You'll want to replace the `updatetoversion=X.X.X.X` with the full build number found on the [Microsoft Update History](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-microsoft365-apps-by-date) site.

As an example, if I wanted to upgrade (or downgrade) to the *May 10 2022 Monthly Enterprise Channel* release[1], I would use `updatetoversion=16.0.14931.20392` as the version number. (Note: the current version number starts with `16.0.x.x` for Office 2016, 2019, 2021, and 365 family of products.)

---

PS: The update history listing is split to show the four channels of updates. The **Current Channel** is the fastest and default setting for most office installs. **Monthly** and **Semi-Annual** are the "slow" and "slowest" in comparison which tend to be more stable. If you have a 3rd-party extension that stops working after an update, consider rolling back to the **Monthly** channel until there's a fix for the issue.

[image: How to read the build number and channel]
[1] *How to read the build number and channel*